# PHP How to access variable from other variable inside class?

Tags: php, class, variables

Here is my class:

```
<?php
class myClass {
    private $a = 1;
    private $b = array(
        'a' => $this->a
    );

    public function getB() {
        return $this->b;
    }
}

$myclass = new myClass();
var_dump($myclass->getB());
```

I want to access variable $a in variable $b. But this shows this error:

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test1.php on line 5

Comment: `$this` is not defined when class variables are declared. After `__construct` is called you can access `$this`

Comment: It's true that can not use $this if class members are not declared. __construct seems the best solution. But I'm trying to use const instead of normal variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access variables by constructor.

Here is some code:

```
class myClass {
    private $a;
    private $b;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->a = 1;
        $this->b = array('a'=>$this->a);
    }

    public function getB() {
        return $this->b;
    }
}

$myclass = new myClass();
var_dump($myclass->getB());
```

Comment: You can find some info from php manual. Take a look : http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to assign a variable property this way. The best way is to probably assign the variable to the array in the constructor instead. So, like this:

```
<?php
class myClass {
    private $a = 1;
    private $b = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->b['a'] = $this->a;
    }

    public function getB() {
        return $this->b;
    }
}

$myclass = new myClass();
var_dump($myclass->getB());
```

Comment: You can't. You're only allowed to assign a constant value directly after declaration. But a variable value (what you are trying) is not allowed. That is were the constructor is designed for. More about it can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: You're right. The best solution is using constructor.